# How to dynamic calling a remoting object and methods

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, remoting

Can I get the Interface information from the remoting URL like http://localhost:8080/xxx.rem?wsdl.

As WebService, I can get the interface information from the service url, http://xXX.xx.xxx.xx/url.svc?wsdl, and compile the assembly by myself code, and invoke methods via reflection.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to obtain metadata information using .net remoting, this have to be done by sharing assembly with classes/interfaces.

Comment: So, if someone shared a remoting url, they should also provide us a interface library or the actual impl library?

Comment: Yes. There is not mechanism like WSDL in .net remoting world